# Proof of the property of Kleene star

Tags: automata

I'm trying to prove some of the properties for the Kleene star operation.

1. (Σε)* = Σ*
2. L ⊆ L*
3. L1 ⊆ L2 implies L1* ⊆ L2*

How do I go about proving these?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The usual way one proves inclusions. For example, 2. Suppose $x\in L$; show that $x\in L^*$, which should be simple given the definition of $L^*$.

Comment: Do you know what those notations mean?